# Validate Mail Status Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, email, sendmail

I' doing something like this:

```
echo "TEST MAIL" | mail -s "subject" "SOME@MAIL.COM"
```

it's send ok! but i must validate in the shell script if the mail was sent or not.

I don't find some way to validate if the mail was sent or not.

EDIT:

The only validation that i have is if the return value in the mail app is 0

```
if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
    echo "Mail enviado a: $destinatarios"

else
    echo "Mail NO enviado a: $destinatarios"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

You should define what "sent" means for you. Return status of "mail" specifies
only if the message was accepted by local MTA or not.

There are still many things that may happen to prevent delivery to the final
recipient. Beginning with there being no network connection on the local
machine and ending with the recipient overlooking your message in his/her
Inbox.

Mail delivery is asynchronous. There are mechanisms for requesting delivery
and read receipts, which seldom work. You may have better luck processing
non-delivery reports. However, all of them may take arbitrary time to arrive.

For that matter, I would say zero exit status of "mail" is as good an
indication of a successfully-sent message as you can get with reasonable
effort.

Comment: Finally i find a "solution" using the mailq command, when i say "sent" i mean it's not in the queue. Thanks for your time !

Comment: @FxckDead Just be aware that the mail can still end up in the queue and be perfectly sent later, e.g. on DNS problems. So a mail ending up in the queue does not necessarily imply a fatal failure.

Answer (score 0):

if you send email to inside of an application, you can modify target application
for "reply"
otherwise as far as i remember there is no simple way.....